# How to Debug System.Core.DLL

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, dll

I'm trying to debug system.core.dll, I have a very complicated issue in which I need walk some methods in linq.

I've enabled framework source stepping.

[image: Frameworksource stepping]

I'm also running a decompiler and I'm hosting my own symbols server, as well as using microsofts symbol server

[image]

No matter what I do, when ever I hit the system.core.dll code there is no option to navigate to source.   I can only view the disassembly.

Does anyone know how to be able to step into system.core.dll

Comment: Which symbol server are you using? I've had good results with [Jetbrains' DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/help/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) running as a symbol server. Everything else you've described appears to be correct.

Comment: I was using all three but it seems like it wouldn't debug unless I cleared my symbol cache

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I needed to clear my symbol cache and rebuild the program.